# specflow with online documentation

Tags: .net, bdd, specifications, specflow

I'd like to introduce some "executable specifications" approaches in my company (.NET). I'd like to keep running with SpecFlow because I am really convinced Gherkin is a great tool. I'd like the test engine to be able to post this living documentation on a wiki, to keep it visible to business people and other stakeholders. A good option should be to be able to add some comments to the scenarios, to keep it as user-friendly as possible.

How would you manage this ? I have heard about **Fitnesse** or **StoryTeller** but it seems they do not handle Gherkin. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Pickles](http://www.picklesdoc.com/). Pickles is a living documentation generator that will convert your .feature files into html pages (or a Word or Excel document). You can host those html pages on an internal webserver.

I am not sure what you mean by "add some comments".

- If you mean "add some comments to the living documentation": you can of course edit the html files but those changes will be lost when you regenerate the living documentation. Those changes will not be sent to the .feature files either.
- If you mean "add some comments so that the readers of the documentation have more information than just the given/when/then steps": Gherkin allows you to write a description at the start of a feature file and at the start of each scenario. Gherkin also allows you to write technical comments by preceding lines with a #. Pickles will always render the descriptions (markdown supported!) and optionally render the technical comments.

Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of Pickles. If you need help getting started with Pickles, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks, sounds good... Just one question : is pickles extensible ? I have in mind the ability to post to a web-service or something like that, this would be the jackpot in my situation.

Comment: It looks like Pickles can output stuff in JSON format. You could build a simple web service application around that.

Comment: Yes, Pickles can output JSON data. You could also modify Pickles to output a custom format. There's a long-standing request to write to Confluence, and I would be happy to accept pull requests for that :-)